# SVG: Huge path versus many line tags

Tags: svg

I am drawing a grid which can easily consists of 600+ vertical and horizontal lines.

Right now I am generating/drawing each grid with a separate  tag.

Can I expect better performance if I generate the lines using on huge path statement. Something like this:

```
<path class="vertical half notLoaded" d="M -4256.849999999999 0  v 950.00 m 52.26 -950.00 v 950.00 m 52.26 -950.00 v 950.00 m 52.26 -950.00 v 950.00 m 52.26 -950.00 v 950.00 m 52.26 -950.00 v 950.00 m 52.26 -950.00 v 950.00 m 52.26 -950.00 v 950.00 m 52.26 -950.00 v 950.00 m 52.26 -950.00 v 950.00 m 52.26 -950.00 v 950.00 m 52.26 -950.00 v 950.00 m 52.26 -950.00 v 950.00 m 52.26 -950.00 v 950.00 m 52.26 -950.00 v 950.00 m 52.26 -950.00 v 950.00 m 52.26 -950.00 v 950.00 m 52.26 -950.00 v 950.00 m 52.26 -950.00 v 950.00 m 52.26 -950.00 v 950.00 m 52.26 -950.00 v 950.00 m 52.26 -950.00 v 950.00 m 52.26 -950.00 v 950.00 m 52.26 -950.00"></path>
```

I can't see a difference on my core i7 with a decent grafik card. Would less performant-setups benefit from this setup?

Comment: I don't think 600 straight lines would cause any system to break into a sweat. Your biggest bottleneck here is probably just network bandwidth, so I would just put the whole grid in a single `<path>` element and try to make the `d` attribute a bit less verbose (i.e., remove every occurrence of `.00` and get rid of all the spaces except where they are separating two numerical digits).

Comment: I'm actually generating the elements on the client using javascript. so bandwidth won't be the issue.

Comment: But is there a difference between having multiple paths which are simple and a big complex path in terms of client performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example of `<pattern>` for SVG. Beats drawing 600+ lines. Draw a box with a crosshair, tile it with `fill`

Edit: Crosshair is optional. That's just asthetics.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="1000" height="1000" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" 
  xml:space="preserve">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="squarePattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" >
        <rect id="box" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" fill="none" stroke="#6185af" stroke-width="1" />
        <path d="M0,10 L20,10 M10,0 L10,20" stroke="#330066" stroke-width="1" />
    </pattern> 
  </defs>
  <rect id="gridlines" x="0" y="0" width="1000" height="1000" fill="url(#squarePattern)" />
</svg>
```